# Oracle form builder , pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I'm new to *Oracle Forms* and I would really appreciate your help!

I have two multiple record blocks in my *Oracle Forms Builder*. Let's name them `block1` and `block2`.
These blocks have the same  three columns - `Sequence`, `Name`, `Date`.

My goal is - upon pressing 'Update' button I need to update `block2` based on changes from `block1`.

Code should compare two blocks. If name or date changed in `block1` (`Sequence` cannot change) then update it in `block2`.

If record is completely gone from `block1` then ***do not*** change anything in `block2`,  just go to the next record.

Please let me know if this is possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nested loop option.

As I don't have your tables (and didn't feel like creating ones), I'm using Scott's `DEPT` table (source for the first block, *Dept 1*) and its copy created as `create table dept2 as select * From dept` (which is source for the second block, *Dept 2*).

This is the layout; screenshot is taken after I pushed the "Update" button:

[image]

- I queried both blocks
- then I updated first block:

  - for deptno = 10, I set dname to xxx
  - for deptnon = 30, I set loc to yyy
- then I pushed the button which copied xxx and yyy to the second block

Code that did that looks like this; read comments within the code.

```
-- go to the second block; navigate to the first record
go_block('dept2');
first_record;

loop
  -- this variable contains current cursor position. It will be used later
  -- with GO_RECORD. Why? To avoid indefinite loop
  :global.rec := :system.cursor_record;

  -- go to the first block and - in a loop - scroll through all its rows
  go_block('dept1'); 
  first_record;
  loop
    -- if DEPTNO columns match, then update second block's values to first block's.
    -- I don't really care whether they are different or not - I perform update unconditionally
    if :dept2.deptno = :dept1.deptno then
         :dept2.dname := :dept1.dname;
         :dept2.loc   := :dept1.loc;
    end if;
    exit when :system.last_record = 'TRUE';
    next_record;
  end loop;

  -- I've done scrolling through the first block. Go to the next row in the second block
  go_block('dept2');
  go_record(:global.rec);
  exit when :system.last_record = 'TRUE';
  next_record;
end loop;
```